# Variable doubles at each run of the function

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

I have the following lines of code:

```
def calculations():
global money_end, RT_portofolio_value, porto, profit, rw_perc, perc_profit

portofolio = 0
portofolio_value = 0
acc_info = mt5.account_info()
money_end = float(acc_info.balance)
for i in range(len(tradesdf)):
    symb = tradesdf.at[i, 'symbol']
    symb = str(symb)
    price = float(mt5.symbol_info_tick(symb).bid)
    portofolio = float(tradesdf.at[i, 'quantity'])
    portofolio_value += portofolio * price
RT_portofolio_value = round((money_end + portofolio_value), 2)

porto = portofolio_value

profit = round(((porto + money_end) - start_amount), 2)

len_win = len([i for i in PnL if i > 0])
len_PnL = len(PnL)
if len(PnL) == 0:
    rw_perc = 0
else:
    rw_perc = (len_win / len_PnL) * 100

if start_amount > 0:
    perc_profit = round(((profit/start_amount) * 100), 2)
else:
    perc_profit = 0

print(porto)
print(portofolio)
print(portofolio_value)
```

For tests, we take a quantity of 12 and a price of 5

The problem is portofolio_value and porto get doubled at the next run of the function

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit:

It seems I added a new piece of code which verify the positions opened. Also, in the dataframe quantity volume I was adding the new check to the existing quantity instead of rewriting so the quantity was doubled each time I was doing the check.